# Using link data as PHP variable input

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I have a link. Eg. `abc.com/qwerty`. I want to extract the part after `/` of every input just like examples below and use it just like a PHP GET input value and store it to a variable `$page`. Essentially, the link `abc.com/qwerty` should work like `abc.com/proc.php?x=qwerty`

```
Typed link        Part to be used as PHP GET input

abc.com/cvbx      cvbx
abc.com/ghvs      ghvx
abc.com/pabc      pabc
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25366965/1408137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns '/cvbx'
$segments = array_filter(explode('/', $request_uri)); //array_filter to remove empty elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url as described at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php .

If you have urls as described there, you can get the path part with:

```
$input = substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),1);
```

substr is to remove the starting /